# Python selenium webdriver : trying to call a javascript function

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, webdriver, syntax-error

i'm trying to get a link for checkout in a e-commerce site, i tryed to click on the span that link  a javascript function:

`<a id="checkout-btn" class="btn btn-lg btn-success pull-right" href="javascript:shop.orders.save()" rel="nofollow"><span>Paga ora</span></a>`)

**with this:**

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='checkout']").click()
```

but it didn't work so i tryed to execute directly the function
**using this command**

`driver.execute_script("shop.orders.save()")`

**but i get this error from python idle:**

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: shop is not defined

if i execute `shop.orders.save()` in the chrome console it work and it link me to the checkout page , so i don't know

anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since it has an id element, can you try

```
 checkout = driver.find_element_by_id('checkout-btn')
 checkout.click()
```

if you do want to go down the xpath road, I'd suggest css

```
checkout = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a[id="checkout-btn"]')
checkout.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='checkout-btn']").click()
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: selenium does not reconize the element, i don't know why,:

`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@id='checkout-btn']"`

i also tryed with : ".//*[@id='checkout-btn']/span" but nothing

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the dot operator.

```
driver.execute_script("javascript:shop\\.orders\\.save()")
```

Comment: you are right i didn't think about this , but with that python get me this :

`selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

i also tryed : `driver.execute_script("shop\.orders\.save()")`, but it's the same, i tryed:

`link = driver.execute_script("return javascript:shop\.orders\.save()")`, i get the same error

Comment: try with double slash escape like driver.execute_script("javascript:shop\\.orders\\.save()")